# Gradient background idea

Tags: lighting

I just curious that how can I make this gradient background?
I use gradient image texture but It didn't look like this. 
Should I use light set ups?

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are many ways to do it but here is one:

- Create a plane that you bend on the background. Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and a *Smooth Shading*.
- Create a *Spot* and play with its parameters (mainly *Lamp Size*, *Spot Shape Size* and *Strength*).
- To give no influence to the *World*, disable all its *Ray Visibility* options .

[image]

Comment: Maybe just flood the cove a bit so your answer shows a gradient in the background? .. If I haven't misunderstood the OP..

Comment: you're right, I've edited, I think it's better